# NEO4J - find all incoming and outgoing edges from a node

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I want to find the difference between the number of all the outgoing edges and the number of all incoming edges to the same node. Nodes are cities and relationships are transfers between them.

I've tried to do this:

```
MATCH ()-[i:TRANSFERS]->(n:City {name:"London"}),(n:City {name:"London"})-[o:TRANSFERS]->() 
RETURN distinct n.name, count(i) AS incoming, count(o) as outgoing, count(o)-count(i) AS difference
ORDER BY outgoing - incoming DESC
```

and this:

```
MATCH ()-[i:TRANSFERS]->(n:City {name:"London"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:City {name:"London"})-[o:TRANSFERS]->() 
RETURN distinct n.name, count(i) AS incoming, count(o) as outgoing, count(o)-count(i) AS difference
ORDER BY outgoing - incoming DESC
```

but they seem not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use size on the relationship pattern for both incoming and outgoing connections :

```
MATCH (city:City {name:"London"})
WITH size((city)-[:TRANSFERS]->()) as out, 
     size((city)<-[:TRANSFERS]-()) as in,
     city
RETURN city, in, out, (out - in) as diff
ORDER BY diff DESC
```

Comment: what does it return ?

Comment: the number of outgoing and incoming edges doesn't correspond to the one i have in the graph! If i do separate queries, the numbers are greater...

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of your data in the browser or provide some data, this query works for sure based on your description

Comment: Maybe some of the relationship names are something other than `TRANSFERS`?

Comment: Also, maybe there's a difference in Neo4j version?  Was `size` introduced in 2.3?

Comment: my favorite cypher clause :) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to match the in and out separately (stealing Christophe's answer here):

```
MATCH (city:City {name:"London"})
WITH city, size((city)-[:TRANSFERS]->()) as out
WITH city, out, size((city)<-[:TRANSFERS]-()) as in,
RETURN city, in, out, (out - in) as diff
ORDER BY diff DESC
```

Comment: haha :) I discovered the console transforms in vars in IN predicates, new console http://console.neo4j.org/r/ih4epf